# $\sin x + \sqrt 3\cos x = 6y - y^2 -11$

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin x + \sqrt{3} \cos x = 6y - y^2 -11 $ where $x$ belongs to $\{0,4\pi\}$ then what should be the value of $x$.

my query is if there are no real values of the quadratic equation in RHS then how can there be any set of values of $x$

Comment: You mean $6y^2-y-11$ instead of $6y^2-y^2-11$ right?

Comment: That argument would only work if the left side equalled $0$.

Comment: @Hushus46 yeh i guess i by mistake wrote that i have made the necessary changes. plz help

Comment: @Mansi So just to make sure, its $6y-y^2-11$ and not what I initially thought $6y^2-y-11$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x + \sqrt{3} \cos x = 6y^2 - y^2 -11\\
\sqrt{1+3}\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{3})= 5y^2 -11$$ note that 
$$-2\leq \sqrt{1+3}\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{3}) \leq 2$$and
$$-11\leq 5y^2-11\leq \infty $$ so when $ -2\leq 5y^2-11\leq 2 $you have some solution for $2\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{3})$

Comment: The OP has edited the question. Now it's $6y-y^2-11$, not $6y^2-y^2-11$.